# GnuWin32 / sed unexpected behavior in Powershell

Tags: windows-7, powershell, sed, gnuwin32

I am using **GnuWin32** tools on Windows Command Line/**Powershell**.

What is see:

```
 11:15 enlil D:\Users\x> Get-ChildItem .gitconfig  | sed "s/ */ /g"


 D i r e c t o r y : D : \ U s e r s \ x


 M o d e L a s t W r i t e T i m e L e n g t h N a m e
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
 - a - - - 6 / 2 3 / 2 0 1 4 4 : 1 1 P M 5 6 . g i t c o n f i g
```

What i expected to see:

```
 11:15 enlil D:\Users\x> ls .gitconfig  | sed "s/ */ /g"


 Directory: D:\Users\x


 Mode LastWriteTime Length Name
 ---- ------------- ------ ----
 -a--- 6/23/2014 4:11 PM 56 .gitconfig
```

**My aim** is to get rid of redundant spaces between columns of data, which are added by PowerShell.
Funny thing is this works perfectly on one computer (with Win8.1), but does not work on other computer with Win7.

And it works for simpler examples:

```
 11:49 enlil D:\Users\x> echo "t  a t" |  sed "s/ */ /g"
 t a t
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

FYI - **Normal output of Get-ChildItems** looks like this:

```
 11:22 enlil D:\Users\x> ls .gitconfig


    Directory: D:\Users\x


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---         6/23/2014   4:11 PM         56 .gitconfig
```

Comment: Why not just use powershell for the whole thing? What is the ultimate goal?

Comment: The ultimate goal is to be able to use gnuWin32 tools like `cut` and `tr` and `sort`. It's my preferred way since I don't really like the Powershell syntax for `Command | Select this and that | Format-table`. Also in powershell a lot of things that is passed through the pipe are objects where in bash they are streams - which is much easier to manipulate for me.

Comment: It is going to be an encoding issue in the environment. One way to avoid it would be to use Out-File to put the output into a file with whatever encoding works then read the file back out to sed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the Unicode. The stuff coming out of sed is Unicode without the 2-byte prefix that PowerShell uses to differentiate between Unicode and ASCII. So PowerShell thinks that it's ASCII and leaves the \0 bytes (the upper bytes from 2-byte Unicode characters) in, which display as blanks. And since internally PowerShell deals in Unicode, it actually expands every original byte into a 2-byte Unicode character. The is no way to force PowerShell into accepting Unicode. The possible ways around it are:

1. Is Unicode coming as input into SED? Unlikely but I think possible. Check that.
2. Make the output of SED start with the Unicode indicator, \uFEFF. This is probably what got missed in the SED source code:

   ```
   _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT); // probably present and makes it send Unicode
   wprintf(L"\uFEFF"); // probably missing
   ```

   You can add the code inside the SED command, something like

   ```
   sed "1s/^/\xFF\xFE/;..." # won't work if SED produces Unicode but would work it SED passes Unicode through from its input
   sed "1s/^/\uFEFF/;..." # use if SED produces Unicode itself, hopefully SED supports \u
   ```
3. Write the output of sed into a file and then read with Get-Content -Encoding Unicode. Note that the switch to file must be done in the command inside cmd.exe, like:

   ```
   cmd /c "sed ... >file"
   ```

   If you just let >file be handled in PowerShell, it will be messed up in the same way.
4. Drop the \0 characters from the resulting text in PowerShell. This doesn't work well with the international characters that create the Unicode bytes containing code 0xA or 0xD - you end up with the line splits instead of them.

Comment: Great, thank you very much for your time and analysis. It's much clearer for me right now.